# Increasing spaces between words,ordering words in columns

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

Is there possibility to easily increase spaces between words in QTextEdit? 
My only idea is to set space key event to insert more whitespaces, but i would better like some setting parameters solution?

Is there way to set words in columns in text edit. What I mean:

```
first word       wordabc      abcd
second word      worda        egdsa
third word       wordb        dafdd
```

With this I have no idea for now.

Answer (score 0):

The `QTextEdit` can render [html](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextedit.html#using-qtextedit-as-a-display-widget), so you could use table elements to achieve what you want.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QTextEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QString html = "<html><body><table>";
  html += "<tr><td>first word</td><td>wordabc</td><td>abcd</td></tr>";
  html += "<tr><td>second word</td><td>worda</td><td>egdsa</td></tr>";
  html += "<tr><td>third word</td><td>wordb</td><td>dafdd</td></tr>";
  html += "</table></body></html>";

  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QTextEdit textEdit;
  textEdit.setHtml(html);
  textEdit.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

You could also apply styling to the table for example by adding the `width` attribute to the `td` tag to push columns apart from each other.

Comment: And how to save document then without html tags? Also each space key event must add <td> tag, and ther will be hard to define columns amount.

Comment: I see your question is more complicated than what I thought. I'm thinking that `QTextEdit` is not appropriate and the input of the columnar data would be better handled in a `QTableWidget`.

Comment: It's supposed to be some code editor. I want to set commands and parameters in columns to be better readable (some kind of autoformating)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `QTextCharFormat` to your text and use `QTextCharFormat::setFontWordSpacing ( qreal spacing )`

Comment: Increases spacing, but words are not in columns. This is key condition because functionality ought to improve readability of commands.

Comment: So your question is not about text decoration but about text markup. That's why you should use some markup language as advised above.

Comment: But the parameters number varies for different commands and also what with saving files without tags?